# Python Modules import

Tags: python, linux, module, package

I have been working on a python project and I am new to it. I have made a small library for my project in which I have several different modules doing different tasks.

For example: I have 5 modules namely add, subtract, multiply, divide and root. I call all these .pyc files into my main.py file and my code runs properly if all of them are in the same folder.

Now, I want to store my main.py at: D:\project\main.py and these 5 .pyc files at : D:\project\Lib\ (In the Lib folder)

I found a solution as to mention the path of the folder Lib into the code but I can not do so as I need to submit the code somewhere and if they try to run this on their PC, it might not import these files.

What would be the possible solution to this?

Comment: Why you call `.pyc` files?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `main.py` file, add the location of your modules to the `path` variable as below.

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + your_path
```

`your_path` which is relative to your project should be like `'./Lib'`.

Try to import modules after the above step. I guess it should work fine. Let me know.

**Note:**

Those `.pyc` files are cache files from executing the `.py` files. You need to worry about the `.py` files and not `.pyc` files.